# Store constructor that accepts parameter in reference

Tags: java, java-8

I have a class

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
}
```

And using `Supplier` in java 8 , I can store the constructor reference like

```
Supplier<Person> personSupplier = Person::new
```

But what if my constructor accepts parameter `age` like

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
    public Person(int age) {this.age = age;}
}
```

Now

```
Supplier<Person> personSupplier = Person::new
```

doesn't works, so what should be correct signature for the `personSupplier`? Obviously I can do something like.

```
Supplier<Person> personSupplier = () -> new Person(10);
```

But age must be different for each person, so it doesn't solve my problem.

May be I should use something else instead of `Supplier`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `java.util.function.Function` in Java and supply `age` when calling `apply`.

E.g.

```
Function<Integer, Person> personSupplier = Person::new;
Person p1 = personSupplier.apply(10);
Person p2 = personSupplier.apply(20);
```

Which is equivalent to

```
Function<Integer, Person> personSupplier = (age) -> new Person(age);
    Person p1 = personSupplier.apply(10);
    Person p2 = personSupplier.apply(20);
```

Comment: also `IntFunction` :D

Comment: I think your first alternative is more concise than your second :-)

Comment: @aioobe You are right , changed words to convey better :)

Answer (score 5):

> So what should be correct signature for the `personSupplier`?

That would be [`Function<Integer, Person>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) or [`IntFunction<Person>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html).

You can use it as follows:

```
IntFunction<Person> personSupplier = Person::new;

Person p = personSupplier.apply(10);  // Give 10 as age argument
```

---

**Follow-up:**

> What if I have `Person(String name, int age)`?

You could use [`BiFunction<String, Integer, Person>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) the same way as above.

---

**Follow-up #2:**

> What if I have `Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age)`?

You won't find a suitable type in the API. You'd have to create your own interface as follows:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface PersonSupplier {
    Person supplyPerson(String firstName, String lastName, int age);
}
```

This could then be used the same way:

```
PersonSupplier personSupplier = Person::new;  // Assuming a Person has a name

Person p = personSupplier.supplyPerson("peter", "bo", 10);
```

Comment: what about `BiFunction`? no `TriFunction` or `QuadFunction` though, :)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I wanted to give a more general answer. :-) Answer updated.

Comment: Unbelievable, there is an `ObjIntConsumer<T>`, but no `ObjIntBiFunction<T,R>`. I guess, the explanation is again, that not all combinations were created to *avoid* an `interface` explosion. You know, to avoid something that already happened…

Comment: Haha, yes. I didn't bother looking for `BiFunction` since I knew there wasn't any `BiConsumer`. The line was drawn quite arbitrarily it seems.